# Removing files having duplicate values across files based on column value and consolidating the remaining files in unix

Tags: unix

I have some files in UNIX

Say Master_101.txt, Master_102.txt, Master_103.txt, Master_104.txt, Master_105.txt

All the files have same header and same columns with ~ separated

The header is: Id~name~desigantion~filename

Data of **Master_101.txt** is:

```
Id~name~desigantion~filename 

11~abcd~SE~ Master_101.txt.

12~efg~ASE~ Master_101.txt

Data of Master_102.txt is :

Id~name~desigantion~filename

21~abcd~SE~ Master_102.txt

22~efg~ASE~ Master_102.txt

Data of Master_103.txt is :

Id~name~desigantion~filename

11~abcd~SE~ Master_103.txt

32~efg~ASE~ Master_103.txt

Data of Master_104.txt is  :

Id~name~desigantion~filename

41~abcd~SE~ Master_104.txt

42~efg~ASE~ Master_104.txt

Data of Master_105.txt is  :

Id~name~desigantion~filename

51~abcd~SE~ Master_105.txt

52~efg~ASE~ Master_105.txt 

53~efdgsdg~ASE-T~ Master_105.txt
```

I need to consolidate all the files into Mater.txt (excluding the files which have duplicates in column “id”)

Here, id 11 is repeated in Master_101.txt and Master_103.txt. Hence we need to consolidate only Master_102.txt, Master_104.txt and Master_105.txt into Master.txt. The final consolidated file **Master.txt** data should be like

```
Id~name~desigantion~filename

21~abcd~SE~MAster_102.txt

22~efg~ASE~MAster_102.txt

41~abcd~SE~MAster_104.txt

42~efg~ASE~MAster_104.txt

51~abcd~SE~MAster_105.txt

52~efg~ASE~MAster_105.txt

53~efdgsdg~ASE-T~MAster_105.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#### get the list of file on which operation to be performed
ls -lrt inp/ | awk '$1~/^-/{print $9}'  > out/filelist

#### getting total count of files
i=`wc -l out/filelist | cut -f1 -d" "`

#### starting the operation
while read line
do
#### comparing a file to rest files so i variable
i=`expr $i - 1`
tail -$i out/filelist | while read line2
do
####checking first field of file with rest files
if [ `awk -F"~" 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1; next}$1 in a {print $0}' inp/$line inp/$line2 | wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
#### if common record is found then delete that files from filelist. sed with "-i" will do the replacement and deletion in file itself. sed with "-e" is used to add multiple replication or deletion operation in single sed.
sed -i -e '/'"$line"'/d' -e '/'"$line2"'/d' out/filelist
i=`expr $i - 1`
break
fi
done
if [ $i -le 0 ]
then
break
fi
done < out/filelist
#### concatening the rest files  into finalfile
xargs cat < out/filelist > inp/finalfile
```

Let me know if you have any doubt. inp and out are directories.

for comparing first 2 fields, change below portion of code in if condition to

```
awk -F"~" 'NR==FNR {a[$1$2]=$1$2; next}$1$2 in a {print $0}' inp/$line inp/$line2
```

Comment: @Shravan.I am new to  unix .Could you please explain the awk and sed command used here how it works briefly.It showed sed -i illegal option.So i split the sed command as sed  '/'"$line"'/d' out/filelist and sed '/'"$line2"'/d' out/filelist.But the script is not removing the filenames having duplicate values.It is consolidating all the files.

Comment: what is shell you are using?? I will add more description to my answer. sed -i will delete the line from file itself. if "-i" is not used it will not delete from file

Comment: @Shravan.I am using ksh.

Comment: it is running fine in ksh also. are you still getting the same error?

Comment: @Shravan.Also please provide me the solution if I need to check for two columns i.e., col1 and col2 together for duplicates

Comment: ,I am still getting the same error..Wil there be any issue like lower version or something like that?

Comment: @Shravan.Please provide me the solution if I need to check for two columns i.e., col1 and col2 together for duplicates

Comment: please check whole code again. I have made many small changes.